# Convert dataframe to hive table in spark scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, hive

I am trying to convert a dataframe to hive table in spark Scala. I have read in a dataframe from an XML file. It uses SQL context to do so. I want to convert save this dataframe as a hive table. I am getting this error:

> "WARN HiveContext$$anon$1: Could not persist `database_1`.`test_table` in a Hive compatible way. Persisting it into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format."

```
object spark_conversion {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

if (args.length < 2) {
  System.err.println("Usage: <input file> <output dir>")
  System.exit(1)
}
val in_path = args(0)
val out_path_csv = args(1)
val conf = new SparkConf()
         .setMaster("local[2]")
         .setAppName("conversion")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

val df = hiveContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
  .option("rowTag", "PolicyPeriod")
  .option("attributePrefix", "attr_")
  .load(in_path)

df.write
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save(out_path_csv)

df.saveAsTable("database_1.test_table")

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing ? saveAsTable did not worked for you?

Comment: So you create a `HiveContext`, that's a good start. **Just use it!** E.g. `df = hiveContext.read....`

Comment: Okay I added the context. However I am getting this error: WARN HiveContext$$anon$1: Could not persist `database_1`.`test_table` in a Hive compatible way. Persisting it into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

saveAsTable in spark is not compatible with hive. I am on CDH 5.5.2. Workaround from cloudera website:

```
df.registerTempTable(tempName) 
hsc.sql(s"""   
CREATE TABLE $tableName (     
// field definitions   ) 
STORED AS $format """) 
hsc.sql(s"INSERT INTO TABLE $tableName SELECT * FROM $tempName")
```

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_spark_ki.html

Comment: With spark 1.6.1 and hive 1.2.1, saveAsTable works fine for me.